# c# uwp Toolkit ImageEx cycle detected

Tags: c#, image, layout, uwp, cycle

In UWP I have this:

```
<GridView x:Name="gvList"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Template}" 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewNoAnimationStyle}">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

My `datatemplate` is like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template" x:DataType="data:Item">
    <customControls:CustomControl
        Model="{x:Bind Mode=OneWay}"
        Width="{Binding ItemWidth, ElementName=customListControl}" 
        Height="{Binding ItemHeight, ElementName=customListControl}"
        ItemPadding="{Binding ItemPadding, ElementName=customListControl}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

In CustomControl there is one ImageEx control:

```
<controls:ImageEx x:Name="imageBackground" Source="{x:Bind Image, Mode=OneWay}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```

There are more then 500 items in list that is populating this GridView.

The problem is I get the "Layout cycle detected.  Layout could not complete." error. If I use the Image instead of ImageEx, everything is working just fine.

But, I need to use ImageEx because it sets it's source asynchroniously, so it populates everything without blocking the UI.

Anyone got idea about this?

Comment: That's a very generic error which normally doesn't help much. Can you create a repo?

Comment: Here is uploaded project https://files.fm/u/6ceennzx

Comment: How to reproduce it?

Comment: Well, use ImageEx instead of Image in CustomControl.

Comment: It works fine on my machine. You need to provide more detailed steps on how to reproduce the issue. Like how you interact with it, your current build number, SDK version, etc.

Comment: There is already a [Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/issues/1328) posted on UWP Community Toolkit Github page.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user AVK and his link https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/issues/1328, I have added this style to my App, and it fixed the issue with ImageEx Layout cycle problem:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:ImageEx">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:ImageEx">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Image
                        Name="PlaceholderImage"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                        Opacity="1.0"
                        Source="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderSource}"
                        Stretch="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderStretch}" />
                    <Image
                        Name="Image"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                        NineGrid="{TemplateBinding NineGrid}"
                        Opacity="0.0"
                        Stretch="{TemplateBinding Stretch}" />
                    <ProgressRing
                        Name="Progress"
                        Margin="16"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        IsActive="False"
                        Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Failed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Loading">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Progress" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsActive">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Progress" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Loaded">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Progress" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsActive">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Progress" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        AutoReverse="False"
                                        BeginTime="0"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Image"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        From="0"
                                        To="1" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        AutoReverse="False"
                                        BeginTime="0"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderImage"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        From="1"
                                        To="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unloaded" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```